# Converting ascii characters back to uni-code in Coldfusion

Tags: database, coldfusion

I have a (postgres) database that cannot accept unicode characters, but they are input as unicode from coldfusion. I convert them to ascii as shown here and store them in the database. That works fine and here is the code I use to convert someones first name (containing Chinese/Korean characters etc) into ascii.

```
<cfset strLen = len(#URL.firstName#)>
<cfset tempCharAll = 'START_TAG'>
<cfloop from="1" to="#strLen#" index="i">
<cfset current_char = mid(#URL.firstName#,i,1)>
<cfset tempChar =  formatBaseN(asc(current_char),16)>
<cfset tempCharAll = tempCharAll & tempChar >
</cfloop>
<cfset #URL.lastName# = #tempCharAll#>
<cfset #URL.firstName# = #tempCharAll#>
```

Now how do I reverse this and make coldfusion convert something back to unicode so the correct Korean/Chinese characters display when some logs in etc?
Thanks.

This code doesn't work:

If I use this code:

```
<CFOUTPUT> input:</br></br></CFOUTPUT> 
<cfset tempChar =  "t">
<CFOUTPUT> #tempChar#</br></br></CFOUTPUT>
<cfset tempChar =  formatBaseN(asc(current_char),16)>
<CFOUTPUT> encoded:</br></br></CFOUTPUT> 
<CFOUTPUT> #tempChar#</br></br></CFOUTPUT>
<cfset varCoded = CharsetDecode(tempChar, "windows-1252")>
<cfset strUnEncoded = CharsetEncode(varCoded, "utf-8")> 
<CFOUTPUT> decoded:</br></br></CFOUTPUT> 
<CFOUTPUT> #strUnEncoded#</br></br></CFOUTPUT>
```

Then it outputs 74 for both decoded and encoded when it should output "t" for decoded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not an encoding expert at all, but I can see you're formatting to base N but not decoding from base N. You also need to get the character using chr() in the last line

```
<CFOUTPUT> input:</br></br></CFOUTPUT> 
<cfset tempChar =  "t">
<CFOUTPUT> #tempChar#</br></br></CFOUTPUT>
<cfset tempChar =  formatBaseN(asc(tempChar),16)>
<CFOUTPUT> encoded:</br></br></CFOUTPUT> 
<CFOUTPUT> #tempChar#</br></br></CFOUTPUT>
<cfset varCoded = CharsetDecode(tempChar, "windows-1252")>
<cfset strUnEncoded = InputBaseN(CharsetEncode(varCoded, "utf-8"),16)> 
<CFOUTPUT> decoded:</br></br></CFOUTPUT> 
<CFOUTPUT> #chr(strUnEncoded)#</br></br></CFOUTPUT>
```

It seems like this could be simplified to the following, but like I said, I'm not all that fimiliar with character encoding

```
<CFOUTPUT> input:</br></br></CFOUTPUT> 
<cfset tempChar =  "t">
<CFOUTPUT> #tempChar#</br></br></CFOUTPUT>
<cfset strUnEncoded =  asc(tempChar)>
<CFOUTPUT> decoded:</br></br></CFOUTPUT> 
<CFOUTPUT> #chr(strUnEncoded)#</br></br></CFOUTPUT>
```

Comment: Thanks. I finally got it working. I had to iterate 4 chars if the input it Korean characters instead of just the "t" but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<cfset varCoded = CharsetDecode(yourString.stringColumn, "windows-1252")>
<cfset strUnEncoded = CharsetEncode(varCoded, "utf-8")>
```

Comment: Sorry that doesn't work. 
If I use this code:

 <CFOUTPUT> input:</br></br></CFOUTPUT> 
 <cfset tempChar =  "t">
 <CFOUTPUT> #tempChar#</br></br></CFOUTPUT>
 <cfset tempChar =  formatBaseN(asc(current_char),16)>
 <CFOUTPUT> encoded:</br></br></CFOUTPUT> 
 <CFOUTPUT> #tempChar#</br></br></CFOUTPUT>
 <cfset varCoded = CharsetDecode(tempChar, "windows-1252")>
 <cfset strUnEncoded = CharsetEncode(varCoded, "utf-8")> 
 <CFOUTPUT> decoded:</br></br></CFOUTPUT> 
 <CFOUTPUT> #strUnEncoded#</br></br></CFOUTPUT> 

Then it outputs 74 for both decoded and encoded when it should output "t" for decoded

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue? Pls let me know..thanks

Answer (score 0):

Update to this answer for CF10 / Railo4.x - there's a new function [Canonicalize()](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Canonicalize) that nicely converts ascii characters to UTF-8 for output.

Example usage:

```
#Canonicalize('h\u00E9',1,1)#
```

You can also use it in CF8 and 9 as described [here](http://www.monkehworks.com/canonicalize-method-in-coldfusion-8-and-coldfusion-9)